# How to close alert message div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to close alert message parent div using javascript?

Problem is parent div is closing but i need to close above parent div.

Here is my code:

```js
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function(){$(this).parent().hide();});
```

```css
.msg-error {
    background:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainalert">

<div class="msg-error">
    <div class"container">
    First error message <a class="btn-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="msg-error">
    <div class"container">
    Second error message <a class="btn-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().hide();});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8b7zt1g7/4/

Or, little fancier:

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function(){$(this).closest('.msg-error').hide();});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to specify the closest parent you want to achieve by using a selector.

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.msg-error').hide();
});
```

With this function you can even change your HTML structure without having to edit your JavaScript code to deal with multiple level of `.parent()` calls, provided that you continue using the same CSS class for the selector.

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/8b7zt1g7/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can chain `.parent()` calls together. Try:

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().hide();});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way, by searching for that main parent div

you can use `closest()` or `parents()`, first option will return first match and seconds will return all matches, your choice

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".msg-error").hide();
});
```

or going the parent twice

```
$(".msg-error .btn-close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent div without jquery

```
<div class="msg-error">
    <div class"container">
    Second error message <a class="btn-close" onclick='Close()'>Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function Close(){
document.getElementsByClassName('msg-error').innerHtml='';
}
<script>
```

Comment: this is not hide, this _remove_, also [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) return  _live HTMLCollection_ so it don't have _innerHtml_ property